# mysql Quiz leaderboard filter by points, time taken

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a quiz report table which shows a report for every quiz a user takes. I need to create a leaderboard from this, which shows the top users best score, filtering by points and then time taken.

here is a link to a sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fbf0/1

I am really struggling as i need to filter the results by two columns for one user, my ideal result would be

```
Results for Quiz id 1
---------------------------------------------------------------   
| user_id  |  points  |  time_spend  |  start_dt  |  quiz_id  |
| 1        |  3       | 0.5          | May,15 2015|  1        |
| 2        |  3       | 0.8          | May,15 2015|  1        |
| 3        |  2       | 0.5          | May,15 2015|  1        |
```

Then a separate query for all quiz's showing the results from the last week.

```
Results from all Quizzs
---------------------------------------------------------------   
| user_id  |  points  |  time_spend  |  start_dt  |  quiz_id  |
| 1        |  3       | 0.5          | May,15 2015|  1        |
| 2        |  3       | 0.8          | May,13 2015|  3        |
| 3        |  2       | 0.5          | May,12 2015|  2        |
```

Comment: What do you mean by filtering? Ordering maybe? And please produce a minimal example without all the irrelevant columns, then include the table definition, sample data and your best try at the query here.

Comment: I have a simply mysql query in for now, but i need to limit this to a user_id best entry:

SELECT user_id, quiz_id, points, time_spend, start_dt
FROM ProQzQuizReport
WHERE quiz_id = 1
ORDER by points DESC, time_spend ASC

I have updated the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fbf0/7

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the query:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from ProQzQuizReport
  order by points desc, time_spend asc) a
group by user_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fbf0/9